# WordPress Jquery Fade in, Fade out effect

Tags: jquery, javascript

I'm following [a tutorial](http://hv-designs.co.uk/2010/01/13/learn-how-to-add-a-jquery-fade-in-and-out-effect/).

I've included the hover.js with the following code:

```
$(function() {
    // OPACITY OF BUTTON SET TO 50%
    $(".imgopacity").css("opacity","0.5");

    // ON MOUSE OVER
    $(".imgopacity").hover(function () {
        // SET OPACITY TO 100%
        $(this).stop().animate({
            opacity: 1.0
        }, "slow");
    },

    // ON MOUSE OUT
    function () {
        // SET OPACITY BACK TO 50%
        $(this).stop().animate({
            opacity: 0.5
        }, "slow");
    });
});
```

Comment: replace the first `$(function() {` with `jQuery(document).ready(function($){`

Comment: @OneTrickPony Those two pieces of syntax are equivalent, the former being [shorthand for the latter](http://api.jquery.com/ready/).

Comment: @AdamBackstrom - it's not quite the same. The second enables jQuery to be called using the `$` namespace.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Going through your source - [jQuery Source](http://bottlelesscoolerreview.bottleless.com/wp-includes/js/jquery/jquery.js?ver=1.6.1) - it seeems that `noConflict()` is getting called right at the end.

To fix your hover.js then would look something like this:

```
jQuery(function($) {    //Allow the use of $ namespace in this function.
    // OPACITY OF BUTTON SET TO 50%
    $(".imgopacity").css("opacity","0.5");

    // ON MOUSE OVER
    $(".imgopacity").hover(function () {

    // SET OPACITY TO 100%
    $(this).stop().animate({
        opacity: 1.0
        }, "slow");
   },

    // ON MOUSE OUT
   function () {

   // SET OPACITY BACK TO 50%
   $(this).stop().animate({
       opacity: 0.5
       }, "slow");
   });
});
```

Regards,

Comment: I've read somewhere that I need to change all instances of $ to Jquery, I tried that but it didn't work.. For the code you sent, what does this mean: jQuery(function($) { and why did it work? thanks!

Comment: @Laurize, the reason it worked is because `jQuery(function($) { ` basically means the following; A `function` that will use the jQuery library _but_ allow `$` to reference jQuery instead (and not some other library that has been added.) See the `$` in the parameter of the anonymous function in your snippet. Ciao!

Answer (score 2):

Do not use "$()" in Wordpress use "jQuery()" instead.